# Vlookup run-time error 9

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vlookup, vba

I built a vlookup code, but cannot seem to understand what I have done wrong. I receive a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range error message.

```
 Cells(lrow + 1, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup( _
    Corp.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("$B$1"), _
    Workbooks("S:\_Shared Files MTL\Corporate Spreads\Weekly Sheets\" & _
               myvalue & "_weekly sheet.xls"). _
                 Sheets("Pricing Sheet").Range("$B$18:$L$232"), 5, False)
```

I am trying to pull data from another workbook into the current workbook (Dim Corp).

The other workbook has a dynamic name and the date (myvalue) changes on a weekly basis.

I am asking the user to enter the date with a message box:

```
myvalue = InputBox("Insert date of file to upload in format yy_mm_dd", "User date", Format(Now(), "yy_mm_dd"))
```

Any ideas as to why the vlookup formula is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a vlookup on a workbook which is not open in Excel. You first need to open the workbook.

Untested:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const MY_PATH As String = "S:\_Shared Files MTL\Corporate Spreads\Weekly Sheets\"

    Dim myValue, fName As String, wb As Workbook, v, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    myValue = InputBox("Insert date of file to upload in format yy_mm_dd", _
                        "User date", Format(Now(), "yy_mm_dd"))

    fName = myValue & "_weekly sheet.xls"

    If Dir(MY_PATH & fName, vbNormal) <> "" Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MY_PATH & fName, ReadOnly:=True)

        v = Application.VLookup(Corp.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("$B$1"), _
              wb.Sheets("Pricing Sheet").Range("$B$18:$L$232"), 5, False)

        sht.Cells(lrow + 1, 2) = IIf(IsError(v), "No match!", v)

        wb.Close False

    Else
        MsgBox "no matching file found!"
    End If

End Sub
```